# How to connect User32.lib to QT project?

Tags: c++, windows, qt-creator, user32, .lib

I want to use User32 function TextOut()

I have tried:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -lUser32 (doesn't help)
INCLUDEPATH ... (doesn't help)
DEPENDPATH ... (doesn't help)
```

I have linked it all static way on 64 bit

Visual studio works fine because there is already user32.lib connected but I need it to be in the QT, please some help!

Comment: I switched the tag from `Qt` (the framework) to `qt-creator` the IDE since the problem is about the IDE.

Comment: Thanks and I remember you have helped me once! Have you any ideas of problem?

Comment: No I don't know. I don't use `winapi` directly in any of my `Qt` code. Also I use `CMake` and `Visual Studio` and not `qt-creator` for everything other than a simple test application.